# Inconsistencies with mySQL delete query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I've encountered an some inconsistencies regarding the results from an SQL query.

Here is the query which I'm using as a prepared statement.

```
delete ROLE_USER_MAP 
from ROLE_USER_MAP inner join ROLE_MANAGER on ROLE_USER_MAP.R_ID=ROLE_MANAGER.R_ID 
where ROLE_USER_MAP.U_ID= ? and ROLE_MANAGER.M_ID= ?
```

Here is how I calling the prepared statement in my Java application.

```
public void deleteRoles(String mID, String uID) throws OperationFailedException
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = this.getConnection();
            this.deleteRoles(mID, uID, conn);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AdminLogger.error(this.getClass(), e);
            throw new OperationFailedException("Failed to remove roles for user.");
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteRoles(String mID, String uID, Connection conn) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try
        {
            stmt = *retrieving ps*
            stmt.setString(1, uID);
            stmt.setString(2, mID);

            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();    // returns 1 here

            if (i < 1)
            {
                throw new SQLException("Failed to remove roles for user.");
            }
        } finally
        {
            stmt.close();
        }
    }
```

It runs fine locally and in SSMS with all rows fitting the where clause being deleted but when I try to deploy it to my hosted server, only the first row in the table is being deleted.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using SSMS (which is for Microsoft SQL Server), why is this tagged MySQL?

Comment: Hi, I am only using SSMS to test out the validity query.

Comment: How can you use SSMS and by extension Microsoft SQL Server to test the validity of a query you're going to execute agsinst MySQL? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I have an exact replica of the hosted database in my local computer. When I say test, I really mean to say I was checking it for any syntax errors and to see if the query is working as I intended.

Comment: And again, testing your queries against a Microsoft SQL Server makes zero sense if you are targeting MySQL. Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL have different syntax.